# SQL switch firstname and lastname

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am Sorry for question but I am stuck. How can I switch row where is lastname and first name = 'Ware, John' to get fullname without comma 'John Ware' ? Thank you very much

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTR( NAME, 1, ( LOCATE( ',', NAME ) ) ) AS FIRSTTNAME,
    SUBSTR( NAME,    ( LOCATE( ',', NAME ) ) ) AS LASTNAME
FROM
    table
```

I am keep getting error:

> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

| Names |
| --- |
| Camerata Si, The |
| Zukerman, Pinchas |
| Phelps, Cynthia |
| Watts, Andre (André) |

Comment: What should happen if a `NAME` value does not contain a comma at all?

Comment: You should fix your data model. Those should be two columns, not one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `REGEXP_REPLACE` function offers one convenient approach here:

```sql
SELECT full_name,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(full_name, '([^,]+),\s*(.*)', '\2 \1') AS full_name_out
FROM yourTable;
```

**Output:**

```
full_name            | full_name_out
Camerata Si, The     | The Camerata Si
Zukerman, Pinchas    | Pinchas Zukerman
Phelps, Cynthia      | Cynthia Phelps
Watts, Andre (André) | Andre (André) Watts
```

Here is a running [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=50f5b0b57074be59503cbca910565ebb) for Postgres.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are genius. It working!

Answer (score 0):

You still need to check for conditions where comma does not exist, etc, but in a crude way:

```
select 
trim(substring(name, position(',' in name)+1)) as FIRSTNAME,
trim(substring(name, 1, position(',' in name)-1)) as LASTNAME 
from Tbl
```